# pgfplots: add margin 'whisker' to barchart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, boxplot

I have the following bar-chart with 5 sets of 2 bars. For some of the individual bars, there is a margin in the (upper) value. I would like to express this similar to a boxplot, with a 'whisker' on top of the bar.
Is there a way to specify a value and plot a whisker in this graph, or do I need to resort to manually drawing the lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.65*\textwidth,
        height = 7cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=14pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        x tick label style  = {text width=1.8cm,align=center,font=\small},
        symbolic x coords={Scenario 1,Scenario 2,Scenario 3,Scenario 4,Scenario 5},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,]
        \addplot[pattern=dots, style={mark=none}]
            coordinates {(Scenario 1, 1500) (Scenario 2,1610) (Scenario 3,1620) (Scenario 4,1590) (Scenario 5,1660) };
            
        \addplot[fill=gray, style={mark=none}]
            coordinates {(Scenario 1, 1520) (Scenario 2,1625) (Scenario 3,1650) (Scenario 4,1605) (Scenario 5,1660)  };

            \end{axis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about adding error bars for that purpose? If the default appearance doesn't fit your need you are free to change it. As a start you could have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485859/95441.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I was searching with the wrong key words.

Comment: Using the format in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470674/adding-error-bars-to-bar-plot I was able to add the required bars.